# Why can I "fold" a range of integers into one half the size without losing information?

Tags: compression, computer-science, floating-point, math

I'm trying to understand [a paper on lossless compression of floating point numbers](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/papers/ils-lcpfpg-05.pdf) and get stuck on one particular step where the authors map a signed integer from a certain range into a range of half the size, losing information that I would think is required. I have a feeling that the authors are using some standard technique which is so obvious to their audience that they don't bother to explain, but which is completely opaque to me.

The value that's being "folded" is the difference between two 23-bit positive integers (the mantissas of a predicted and an actual floating point value) which lies between 1 - 2<sup>23</sup> and 2<sup>23</sup> - 1. The authors move the numbers with the highest values (negative and positive) "inwards", so the resulting range is half the size and each number (except 0) maps to two possible values from the original range. This makes me wonder how the process should ever be reversed to determine the original value. In the authors` own words:

> We compute the signed corrector that is the shortest modulo 2<sup>23</sup> and the number `k` that specifies the tightest interval (1-2<sup>k</sup> , 2<sup>k</sup>) into which this  corrector falls. Next, this number `k`, which ranges between 0 to 22 is compressed [...]. Finally the `k + 1` significant bits of the corrector are compressed.

The pseudocode for this is given as:

```
void comp mantissa(int expo, int a, int p) {
  // c will be within [1-2^23 ... 2^23 -1]
  int c = a - p;
  // wrap c into [1-2^22 ... 2^22 ]
  if (c <= -(1<<22)) c += 1<<23;
  else if (c > (1<<22)) c -= 1<<23;
  // find tightest [1-2^k ... 2^k ] containing c
  int k = 0;
  // loop could be replaced with faster code
  int c1 = (c < 0 ? -c : c);
  while (c1) { c1 = c1 >> 1; k++ }
  // adjust k for case that c is exactly 2k
  if (k && (c == 1<<(k-1))) k--;

  // .. further code omitted for brevity
}
```

Ignoring the actual compression method, the output consists of `c` and `k`. What I don't get is: **How can I restore the original `c` from `c` and `k` when the "wrap c into" part above just maps half of the potential range onto the other half?** I tried this on paper with 4 instead of 23 bits and I just don't get it.

Comment: This is a classic example of how hard it is to pose the question right when you are really stuck. Kudos to jcd for figuring out what my problem was. Maybe this could be edited into something which is more generally useful, I'll appreciate hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the author says they are considering the significands "modulo 2^23", that means the numbers will be stored in 23-bit integers, so numbers that differ by multiples of 2^23 will be "the same" since the bit pattern is the same.  (See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularArithmetic.html)

Since the "wrapping" code after c=a-p only adds or subtracts 2^23 to c, when you later reverse this by computing a = c+p you get the right value as the 2^23 doesn't matter.

Here's an example in binary...

```
a =             00000000000000000000001
p =             10000000000000000000100
c = a-p =      -10000000000000000000011
```

then, since c<=-(1<<22), the wrapping occurs...

```
c = c+(1<<23) = 11111111111111111111101
```

Which is then encoded.  Then later, you can get back a from c and p:

```
a = c+p =      100000000000000000000001
```

but since this is stored in a 23-bit integer, this is equivalent to:

```
a =             00000000000000000000001
```

which is the original a.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This would have taken me ages to notice, I was looking completely the wrong way.